# Create a session with necessary cookies using Perl

Tags: perl, session, cookies, lwp

I will try to give as many details as possible.

Using **Perl**, I am trying to download the list of Impact Factors of all Journals for the JCR (Journal Citation Reports) from the Web of Knowledge (WoS) (url: http://admin-apps.webofknowledge.com/JCR/JCR?RQ=SELECT_ALL&cursor=1). It should be noted that the link is only accessible using IPs from most academic institutions, like mine, or from paying users.

Whenever I visit the link (**using the browser**) and sometime has passed, the session has expired so I need to click on a link (http://admin-router.webofknowledge.com/?DestApp=JCR) to establish a new session. Using my rudimentary knowledge of Firebug I found that when I am authenticated I get a cookie named jcrsid with a random string value.

My question is the following:
Using **Perl's LWP module**, what steps should I take in order to establish a session and download the web pages I need. (If I use LWP to download the page, i download exactly the same page that appears when I am asked to establish a new session using the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set a `cookie_jar` on your LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-cookie_jar) object. LWP::UA will then store all the cookies it encounters in a [HTTP::Cookies](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies) object and handle them for you. They'll be sent with every request.

You can use an empty hash reference `{}` to store your cookie in memory. There is no need to use a file for this kind of job.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    cookie_jar => {},
);
```

That's it. Then you would to `get` the link that gives you the login cookie first.

```
my $res_login = $ua->get('http://admin-router.webofknowledge.com/?DestApp=JCR');
die $res_login->status_line unless $res_login->is_success;
```

Afterwards you can go about loading your pages. The cookie will be sent automatically.